# Implementing pagination with Mongoose and graphql-yoga

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql

I am experimenting with graphql and have created a simple server using graphql-yoga. My Mongoose product model queries my database and both resolvers return data as expected. So far it all works and I am very happy with how easy that was. However, I have one problem. I am trying to add a way to paginate the results from graphQL.

#### What did I try?

1) Adding a limit parameter to the Query type.

2) Accessing the parameter through args in the resolver

#### Expected behaviour

I can use the args.limit parameter in my resolver and use it to alter the Mongoose function

#### Actual behaviour

I can't read the arg object.

Full code below. How do I reach this goal?

```
import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga'
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import {products} from "./models/products.js"

const connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://myDB')

const prepare = (o) => {
  o._id = o._id.toString()
  return o
}

const typeDefs = `
  type Product {
    _id: String
    name: String
    description: String
    main_image: String
    images: [String]
  }

  type Query {
    product(_id: String): Product
    products(limit: Int): [Product]
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    product: async (_id) => {
      return (await products.findOne(_id))
    },
    products: async (args) => {
      console.log(args.name)
      return (await products.find({}).limit(args.limit))
    },
  },
}

const server = new GraphQLServer({ 
  typeDefs, 
  resolvers 
})

server.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for a field are the second parameter passed to the resolver; the first parameter is the value the parent field resolved to (or the `root` value in the case of queries/mutations). So your resolvers should look more like this:

```
product: (root, { _id }) => {
  return products.findOne(_id)
}
```

Comment: Tested and immediately works. Thanks for helping a graphql beginner out :)

Comment: @daniel i am also testing stuff with graphql-yoga and mongoose, 
i am having successfull crud operation but as we know it don't updates cache automaticly
while deleting operation it is successfully perform on backend through query and returns deleted object `id` but same thing when is done with front end interface it returns null
do you have any idea why this so? it will be very time saving you could prompt me where i have to update my stuff thanks

Comment: @daniel-rearden

Comment: @HánzláHábib I'm not sure how this relates to the original post or this answer. You should post this as a separate question, providing as much information as possible, including the relevant code.

Comment: @DanielRearden thankyew for responding i will create another question will mention you if i could so that you can see that in detail
thanks